# how to know expiration time of ASP.NET_SessionId from cookie file in php?

Tags: php, cookies, sessionid

i am using curl to login to a remote site and the remote site sends me cookie and i save it as cookies.txt.I use the cookie to get the rest of protected pages without having to login using curle again!

Now i want to know when asp.net sessionId expires from the cookie file. Is that possible ?The reason that i want to know when it expires is that i want re login using curl and get new sessionId.(currently the session id stops worked after like 2 hours)

How i can check cookie.txt modification/creation date and if it is longer say 1 hour, i just re login to get new cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Most sites won't send back a cookie with the expires date and will handle when to log you off server side.  The reason for that would be that if it was grabbing when to log you out from the cookie you could easily modify it and never get logged out which wouldn't be very secure.